# When performing arithmetics code gives unusual results

Tags: python, math

Python script seems to do incorrect arithmetics.

```
import _thread
import time

def mult(pixel : int, multiplier : tuple) -> float:
    "multiplies either r,g,b pixel by row vector (0.257, 0.504, 0.098),(-0.148,-0.291,0.439),(0.439,-0.368,-0.071))"

    sum=0
    for mul in multiplier:
        sum += (pixel * mul)
        print(sum)
    return sum

redMul = [0.257, 0.504,0.098]
greenMul = [-0.148, -0.291, 0.439]
blueMul = [0.439, -0.368,-0.071]

redAdd = 16
greenAdd = 128
blueAdd = 128

try:
   _thread.start_new_thread(mult,(1,blueMul))
except:
    print("Error: unable to start thread")
```

code outputs:

```
0.439
0.07100000000000001
1.3877787807814457e-17
```

when expecting:

```
0.439 
0.071
0
```

What is the cause of this error and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Floating point math: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Adjust your expectations or use the function `round()` on the final results if you only want a few decimal places of accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python script does not do incorrect arithmetic, it is just the way floating-point arithmetic is.

The main principle you need to be aware of when using `float` (double floating point precision in Python) is that it is an *approximation* of the actual value. Unless the value is having denominator of power 2 - like 1, 2, 4, 0.5, 0.25, etc, the value cannot be exactly represented by `float`. It is always *approximation*, up to the 15/16-th digit.

Thus all your results:

```
0.439
0.07100000000000001
1.3877787807814457e-17
```

Are correct... up to the 15/16th significant digit, that is:

```
0.439
0.0710000000000000
0.000000000000000 #(thus you have 1 e-17 as your 17-th digit)
```

`float` does not guarantee precision beyond the 15-th/16-th digit

If you really need higher precision than 15-16-th digit, consider using `decimal`

Answer (score 1):

`sum = round(sum, 3))`

limit float to 3 decimal points, and then do the arithmetic

```
def mult(pixel : int, multiplier : tuple) -> float:
    "multiplies either r,g,b pixel by row vector (0.257, 0.504, 0.098),(-0.148,-0.291,0.439),(0.439,-0.368,-0.071))"

    sum=0
    for mul in multiplier:
        sum += (pixel * mul)
        sum = round(sum, 3)
        print(sum)
    return sum
```

Comment: round(sum,3) rounds sum to 3dp, what does the rest of your solution add?

Comment: im refering to the " float("{0:.3f}".format()) "

Comment: @LouAnimashaun I modified the code. that's for string formatting. it is useless in this case